# nullpointer exception for getActionbar()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I imported this project from eclipse, it was working fine there Due to `multidex` I supposed to migrate, after I migrated to Android studio I had suffered many problems I fixed all but now because of this line:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(103, 58, 183)));
```

It shows `NullPointerException` for pre lollipop devices kindly help me to come out of this.

Comment: Your NullPointerException might not be for the getActionBar but for the setBackgroundDrawable (or for both of them). I re-posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official reference, [setBackgroundDrawable was deprecated in API level 16](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

And it says: *use [setBackground(Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) instead*. So,

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(103, 58, 183)));
```

may work.